# How to find the threshold that will yield the desired number of array elements

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array of numbers and a target count, I want to find the threshold such that the number of element that are above it will be equal the target (or as close as possible).

For example.

```
arr = np.random.rand(100)
target = 80
for i in range(100):
    t = i * 0.01
    if (arr > t).sum() < target: break
print(t)
```

However this is not efficient and it is not very precise, and perhaps someone has already solved this problem.

**EDIT:**

In the end I found `scipy.optimize.bisect` ([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html)) which works perfectly.

Comment: sum the numbers starting at the end to the first and stop when the sum is above the target, then decide if you need the previous sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `scipy.optimize.bisect`

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np

def compute_cutoff(arr:np.ndarray, volume:float) -> float:
    """
    Compute the cutoff to attain desired volume.  
    Returns the cutoff, such that (arr > cutoff).sum() == volume
    or as close as possible.
    :param np.ndarray arr: an array with values (0 .. 1)
    :param float volume: desired volume in number of voxels
    """
    tolerance = max(1,volume*.01)
    gross_diff = lambda y: y - volume if abs(y - volume) > tolerance else 0
    err_fn = lambda x : gross_diff((arr > x).sum())
    # probably this [-2,2] could be tighter [0,1], but just to be safe.
    return scipy.optimize.bisect(err_fn, -2, 2, maxiter=50, disp=False)



arr = np.random.rand(100)
t = compute_cutoff(arr, 80)
print(t)
```

This prints a value close to 0.2

Answer (score 1):

You can try binary search for your value (create threshold array first):

```py
def binary_search(arr, target, thresholdarr):
    low = 0
    high = len(thresholdarr) - 1
    mid = 0

    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) // 2

        s1 = (arr > thresholdarr[mid]).sum()
        s2 = (arr > thresholdarr[mid - 1]).sum()

        if s1 < target and s2 >= target:
            return thresholdarr[mid]
        elif s2 < target:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1

    # If we reach here, then the element was not present
    # return last element of thresholdarray
    return thresholdarr[high]


np.random.seed(42)
arr = np.random.rand(100)

thresholds = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
x = binary_search(arr, 80, thresholds)
print(x)
```

---

Prints:

```
0.16
```

---

Here is quick benchmark using `perfplot`:

```py
import perfplot
import numpy as np

def search_roman_perekhrest(arr, target, t_arr):
    return t_arr[np.abs((arr > t_arr[:, None]).sum(1) - target).argmin()]


def normal_search(arr, target):
    for i in range(100):
        t = i * 0.01
        if (arr > t).sum() < target:
            break
    return t


def binary_search(arr, target, thresholdarr):
    low = 0
    high = len(thresholdarr) - 1
    mid = 0

    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) // 2

        s1 = (arr > thresholdarr[mid]).sum()
        s2 = (arr > thresholdarr[mid - 1]).sum()

        if s1 < target and s2 >= target:
            return thresholdarr[mid]
        elif s2 < target:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1

    # If we reach here, then the element was not present
    # return last element of thresholdarray
    return thresholdarr[high]


np.random.seed(42)
thresholds = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n),
    kernels=[
        lambda arr: binary_search(arr, 80, thresholds),
        lambda arr: normal_search(arr, 80),
        lambda arr: search_roman_perekhrest(arr, 80, thresholds),
    ],
    labels=["bin_search", "normal_search", "search_roman_perekhrest"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(7, 16)],
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=None,
)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While suggested binary search is reasonably fast, here's a one-line alternative for relatively small arrays (note, the intermediate calculation forms matrix `arr.size` x `arr.size`). It compares the initial `arr` and thresholds array at once to find the absolute differences and the position of the "closest" threshold:

```
target = 80
t_arr = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
t = t_arr[np.abs((arr > t_arr[:, None]).sum(1) - 80).argmin()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation looks like O(m*n) complexity, where `n` is length of the array and `m` is length of the threshold candidates you're iterating over.

Sorting the array and selecting `target` element from the end will likely do the job more efficiently.

BUT If your array can contain equal values (otherwise you could have always selected a precise threshold) complications start. Your example most likely is not that case, but I am not sure what your actual data looks like.

So the sorting and picking from the end could be further continued by searching neighbour values and checking if they're better fit than initial candidate.

Here's my code:

```
def get_threshold(array, target):
    sorted_array = sorted(array)[::-1]
    candidate = sorted_array[target]
    
    next_val_idx = target
    prev_val_idx = target
    
    while prev_val_idx < len(array) and sorted_array[prev_val_idx] == candidate:
        prev_val_idx += 1
        
    while next_val_idx >= 0 and sorted_array[next_val_idx] == candidate:
        next_val_idx -= 1
        
    candidates = [candidate]
    if next_val_idx >= 0:
        candidates.append(sorted_array[next_val_idx])
    if prev_val_idx < len(sorted_array):
        candidates.append(sorted_array[prev_val_idx])
        
    return min(
        candidates,
        key=lambda t: abs(target - (array > t).sum())
    )

get_threshold(np.array([4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]), 2)
```

Output:

```
4
```

---

However, if you don't expect equal element - probably `np.quantile` will work?

```
np.quantile(arr, q=1 - target / len(arr))
```